# Single Responsibility Principle for CRUD operations against a collection

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to understand how to logically separate CRUD responsibilities so to adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).

As I understand the definition of SRP, a single responsibility may not necessarily be a single behavior, but instead be a  collection of behaviors with a well-defined, logical boundary from others.

In my example, RestaurantMenu is nothing more than a collection.  I understand that there are more efficient ways to represent this, such as with a dictionary, but that is beyond the intent of this example.  My RestaurantMenu has no behavior assigned to it because it remains unclear to me as to whether defining any further behavior by it would breach the SRP.  It feels rather uncomfortable instantiating and calling separate CRUD objects through a Manager object rather than through methods in RestaurantMenu, so that is why I've decided to ask the audience here for some guidance.

Does the following example pass the SRP litmus test?

```
class RestaurantMenu(object):                                                   

  def __init__(self, title, creator, catalog_type, restaurant):              
      self._title = title                                                    
      self._creator = creator                                                
      self._catalog_type = catalog_type                                      
      self._restaurant = restaurant                                          
      self._menuitems = dict()                                               


class MenuManager(object):                                                     
  """Responsibility                                                          
     --------------                                                          
     Coordinates CRUD related activities with a menu                        
  """                                                                        

  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu                                                      

  def add_menu_item(self, item, value):                                      
      menu_item_adder = AddMenuItem(self._menu)                              
      menu_item_adder(item, value)                                           

  def del_menu_item(self, item):                                             
      menu_item_deleter = DelMenuItem(self._menu)                            
      menu_item_deleter(item)                                                

  def update_menu_item(self, existing_item, new_info):                       
      menu_item_updater = UpdateMenuItem(self._menu)                         
      menu_item_updater(existing_item, new_info)                             

  def get_menu_items(self):                                                  
      menu_item_getter = GetMenuItems(self._menu)                            
      menu_item_getter()             

class GetMenuItems(object):                                                    

  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu                                                      

  def __call__(self):                                                        
      print(self._menu._title)                                               
      print('='*len(self._menu._title))                                      
      for key, value in self._menu._menuitems.items():                       
          print(key, value)                                                  


class AddMenuItem(object):                                                     

  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu                                                      

  def __call__(self, item, value):                                           
      if item not in self._menu._menuitems:                                  
          self._menu._menuitems[item] = value                                
          print('Item added:', item)                                         
      else:                                                                  
          print('Item already exists.  Please update instead.')              


class DelMenuItem(object):                                                     

  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu                                                      

  def __call__(self, item):                                                  
      popped = self._menu._menuitems.pop(item)                               
      print('Item removed:', popped)


class UpdateMenuItem(object):                                                  

  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu                                                      

  def __call__(self, existing_item, new_info):                               
      self._menu._menuitems.update(existing_item=new_info)                   
      print('Item updated:', existing_item, ' with', new_info)               


def main():                                                                    

  mymenu = RestaurantMenu("Joe's Crab Shack 2014 Menu",                       
                         "Joe Schmoe",                                       
                         "Restaurant",                                       
                         "Joe's Crab Shack")                                 

  menumanager = MenuManager(mymenu)                                          

  menumanager.add_menu_item('longneck_clams', 7.00)                          
  menumanager.add_menu_item('1 pound lobster', 15.00)                        
  menumanager.add_menu_item('lobster chowder', 9.00)                         

  print('-'*50)                                                              
  menumanager.get_menu_items()                                               


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                     
  main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible definition of SRP compliance is that there should only be [one reason for a class to change](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf).

This makes it very hard to call SRP or not on a piece of code in the abstract -- it basically depends on what will happen to evolve together and separately over time in your application.

Generally speaking though, the UI is one of the primary things that might evolve independently from other parts of a program. Users will keep wanting to make little display adjustments over the course of a project, and it's a nice thing to be able to modify the presentation logic without fearing to break the rest of the system. Persistence is another thing you might want to change, either as a result of new architectural decisions or temporarily, depending on the context (swapping in dummy persistence objects in tests for instance).

This is why in most real-world applications, I would tend to split up classes by technical responsibility rather than business operations on a same entity like C/R/U/D.

If you look closely at your current implementation, you'll notice patterns in your classes. They all fiddle with a `MenuManager` and the `MenuItems` *stored* in it. They all *print* things to the screen.

If you want to change something in the way data is displayed or stored, you'll basically have to touch all these classes. I'm not saying it's a serious flaw in the case of a small simple system like this, but in a larger application it might well be a problem.

Put another way, your example makes it easy to have menu updates done through a graphical interface into a SQL database, menu inserts done via a command shell into flat files, and menu reads spitting out an XML file with data gathered from a web service. This might be what you want to do in very particular circumstances, but not most of the time...

Comment: I'm starting to understand.  What would such a design as you describe look like?  Would you mind sharing a fiddle?

Comment: I'm afraid my Python skills are somewhat limited, but there's a convenient example here : https://github.com/Finglas/Playground/blob/master/hexagonal.architecture/example.py You'll recognize popular design patterns such as Repository and Controller that help you enforce SRP. The overall approach mentioned is Hexagonal Architecture (http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) -- it doesn't matter so much in a small program like this, but the idea is to identify big concentric zones of single-responsibility objects in your system, each zone having a higher single responsibility itself.

Comment: The first part of [this presentation](http://fr.slideshare.net/DrTrucho/python-solid) also illustrates what I was saying with code.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to complement @guillaume31 answer, but I don't think it will fit in a comment.

> As I understand the definition of SRP, a single responsibility may not necessarily be a single behavior, but instead be a collection of behaviors with a well-defined, logical boundary from others.

However you say you understand this, your code shows the opposite. You've spread a high cohesive group of tasks through several classes. Why this is bad?

How many times do you have the following code?

```
  def __init__(self, menu):                                                  
      self._menu = menu
```

I'm to lazy to count it, but you'll notice that this is an unecessary code duplication.

In this particular simple case, there is no problem, in deed, but if you application grow, you'll have a huge headache.

In some countries, it's valentine's day tomorrow, so you should remember how to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  Lesson learned -- keep the CRUD together to increase cohesion.